# json file not working in android app with ionic

Tags: android, json, ionic-framework

I am Using Ionic framework develop with android app.simple json file not working in my app! the same application work with only local browser,when i run in my mobile this app not working on json file using $http. i getting this error,

GET http://localhost:8383/LoginCtrl/www/js/namerecords.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
How to work with json file in mobile,below i attached my code.
```

`Controller.js`

```
app.controller('recordsCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8383/LoginCtrl/www/js/namerecords.json')
            .success(function(response){
                console.log(response.records);
         $scope.persons = response.records;       
    });
});
```

Comment: try to include plugin called `whitelist`

Comment: You need to change "localhost" to your server address!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'localhost', you need to change the URL to your server's address since the server is not running in your mobile phone.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

1.The $http Link is not correct
2.If you are Check the API in ionic framework .do it mobile only.that api content not work in web browser.only mobile.